# Dynamic routing PHP & AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

```js
.when('/FOO', {
  templateUrl: 'app/components/forums/id/forums.php'
})
```

```html
<td><a ng-click="setRoute('FOO')"href="forums.php?id=<?= $f_id;?>"><?php echo $f_name;?></a></td>
```

**Soooo.**

Some background. I'm making a forum, I want to do it with AngularJS.

**F_id** and **F_name** has been declared earlier. *(Not really relevant to the problem here.)*

What I want to do, is dynamic routing. How can I make angular to work with the php's ***?id=id*** mechanism? So that when I click on that forum it will open the right forum?

- Dynamic routing, how?

Comment: You have to decide, do you want angular routing or navigation by href and page reloading, if you want to load content from php i suggest you define controller on route and params that you want to pass and then in controller use $http.get() to get content that you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you want to start with a route of the following form, your template should be generic and display the values fetched for a forum whose details will be passed to the ForumController.

```
.when('/FOO/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/forums/forums.php',
        controller: 'ForumController',
        resolve: {
          forum: function ($routeParams) {
             // fetch your forum details here using $routeParams.id
          }
        }
})
```

Although for completeness I should mention that you can in fact define templateUrl as a function so that you can return a dynamic template if you really want to, but I suspected that is not what you want.

```
.when('/FOO/:id', {
        templateUrl: function ($routeParams) {
            return 'app/components/forums/' + $routeParams.id + '/forums.php';
        }
})
```

Comment: Please see my edit above, if your PHP script already get the forumId from the url and renders the page correctly, In this case you can define templateUrl as a function which would return your template.